# =-sign in Office 365 ContactFolders API call not working

Tags: office365

I am consuming the Office 365 REST API (using basic authentication) at outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/.

The call to outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/ContactFolders('Contacts') is returning all of the Contacts in the 'root' of the Contacts folder. But I would like to get all users - also in the (sub)folders.

I can get a list of folders in Contacts using:
outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/Users('E-MAILACCOUNT')/ContactFolders('IDOFTHECONTACTFOLDER')/ChildFolders

This shows all of the folders, like this:

```
  {
      "Contacts@odata.navigationLink": "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/Users('XX')/ContactFolders('...WCSksCdABO4VgFTAAA=')/Contacts"
```

Now the problem is, when I call this URL, the trailing = is replaced by %3D.

I can see this in the returning JSON message, it reads:

```
{
  "@odata.context": "https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/$metadata#Users('E-MAIL')/ContactFolders('...ksCdABO4VgFTAAA%3D')/Contacts",
```

Below it returns ALL of the results from the root of the Contacts folder and NOT the Contacts in this folder I requested.

I think the API cannot find the folder ID I am requesting because the trailing `=`, part of the folder ID, is replaced by `%3D`.

Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for trying the API. This is a bug where the filter on subfolders is not being respected. We are tracking to fix this soon.

Comment: Rohit, thanks for your answer. Any time path on when to expect this fix? Thanks a lot

Comment: This bug is high in the list of fixes we are working on. I don't have a specific timeline that I can share though.

Comment: @RohitNagarmal-MSFT have you guys rolled out a fix for this bug?  Running into this issue when trying to create a contact in a user's contact folder.  The contact is being successfully created but not being filed in the folder requested

Comment: @jgraft  The issue that was originally posted is fixed. where the url to contact folder with a trailing "=" is now working ../ContactFolders(..nAAA=')/Contacts. Can you share the exact issue you are facing? Are you unable to create a contact in a given contactfolder?

Comment: @RohitNagarmal-MSFT yeah we are still having issues. I will take another look at it and raise a new stack overflow question if we can't get it to work.  Thank you for the link.