# Creating contact in folder with Office 365 Rest API

Tags: office365

Similar question to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24615409/sign-in-office-365-contactfolders-api-call-not-working/24663323?noredirect=1#comment46200820_24663323) however I am using the v1.0 Office 365 Rest API and it looks like that question was based on accessing the EWS Managed API.

Anyways, as I discussed in the comments with @RohitNagarmal-MSFT, we are trying to use the Rest APIs to create a contact in a contact_folder.

Code sample is using ruby and RestClient gem.

```
folder_id = "...AAA="
url =  "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/contactfolders/#{folder_id}/contacts"
response = RestClient.post url, params.to_json, authorization: auth
```

Expected behavior: contact created in the specified contact folder

Observed behavior: contact is created but in the user's main contact folder.  However the response would make it seem that it has something to do with the trailing '=' on the folder_id.

```
   response #=> 
{
"@odata.context"=>  "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/$metadata#Me/ContactFolders('...AAA%3D')/Contacts/$entity",
"@odata.id"=>"https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/Users('user@domain.onmicrosoft.com')/Contacts('...AAA=')",
 ...
 }
```

Comment: @RohitNagarmal-MSFT as discussed.  Would love any thoughts you may have.  Thanks so much!

Comment: how we can update contact with same API

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate to [Contacts are getting created only in root folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28238849/contacts-are-getting-created-only-in-root-folder/28239672). This is a known problem with the API. I have a bug filed with our dev team. I don't have a timeframe to share on a fix at this point, but I can update this thread when I know more.